# Java lock Conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose I have the following code:

```
private final ReentrantLock resourcesLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
private Condition resourcePresentCondition= resourcesLock.newCondition();

public void requestRes() throws InterruptedException {
    resourcesLock.lock();
    try {
        if(resources.isEmpty()) {
            if(!resourcePresentCondition.await(Config.STARVE_TIME_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                if(resources.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        //No resources left if other threads gather them first
        Resource resource = resources.removeFirst();
    } finally {
        resourcesLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Now, multiple threads enter the requestRes() method and if no resources are present, they all wait on the condition. Another method generates resources and calls `resourcePresentCondition.signalAll()`. After this, if time has not run out(or if it did and there are resources present -- just to avoid cases where it all happens at the same time), a resource is consumed.

The problem is that sometimes resources are emptied and threads that got the signal for resourcePresentCondition throw exceptions because resources list is empty(.removeFirst() exception).

What would be the best solution to avoid this and make the threads resume the wait(not start over) for resourcePresentCondition?

Comment: I would take a look at [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: add another test `resources.isEmpty()` before the `removeFirst`.

Comment: @Nico you might want to take a look at [high level concurrency objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html)

Comment: Maybe it's better to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue or something similar to store resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use just `signal()` instead of `signalAll`, calling `signal()` once for every resource added. This makes sure that each thread that was signaled is guaranteed to have 1 resource to consume.

This makes the other threads wait until signalled or timeout occurs. There's no way to resume an existing `await()`, and you don't want to start writing custom logic to keep track of the time that has been spent waiting.

Since you're using a fair lock (`new ReentrantLock(true);`) (as you should in this case) it doesn't even make sense to signal *all* of the threads. You don't want a consumer that just had a resource to be competing for another one.

A different approach which would simplify things would be to use a fair `Semaphore`.

```
// Consumer
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0, true);

public void requestRes() throws InterruptedException {    
    if(!semaphore.tryAcquire(Config.STARVE_TIME_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        return; // No resource available, and timed out

    Resource resource = resources.removeFirst();
}

// Producer, giving out as many semaphores as resources produced
semaphore.release(resources.size());
```

Comment: The problem with the frist approach(and also the second I believe) is that sometimes `signal()` is too late and even though some producer produced resources, consumers "die" because they didn't get the signal in time. The timestamp is the same for those cases.(produce() & "death event").

Comment: _You don't want a consumer that just had a resource to be competing for another one_ - This wouldn't be the case, as there's a "full time" after consuming a resource, but anyway, the `signal()` way is closer to the solution. (+ the fair lock)

Comment: One way of doing it was to actually _cheat_ with the timeout, and block running out of time if resources are generated. This raises the same problem as before, cannot resume the wait if resources get consumed by other threads.

Comment: It's not `signal()` that's too late. It's you having too many consumers and/or a too short timeout for the amount of resources you're producing. I gave you *two* perfectly valid solutions, so stop daydreaming about resuming an await, it's not possible. You also seem to have missed the point about a consumer competing for a resource after it just "ate".

Comment: You're basically comparing the behaviour of my working code to the *assumed* "correct" behaviour of your code. Use the simple code provided with `Semaphore`, if you see consumers timing out, then use less consumers and/or a longer timeout. Then profile to get the wanted performance. Or you can pretend that you know better than I do, waste your time, and try to write "more clever" code that fails in ways you can't even imagine.

Comment: It's not a too short timeout, in fact it doesn't matter what timeout I use, it's the fact that it all happens at once(produce() vs death event of waiting threads). There are not that many threads(the issue is with 3 waiting threads). I might have missed to point out that resources are produced when a consumer dies, and because it's the same waiting time for everyone initially, some consumers die even if they shouldn't, as another died already, thus resources exist. I'll try to set an offset(random amount of time) between them, so it doesn't all happen at once.

Comment: You might be right, I might've missed the point on consumer competing for a resource. Also, never said _I know better_, I just asked some questions and explained my issues. In fact, I've got very little experience with multithreading. It's not like I thrashed your response or assaulted you to answer my question, you could've just ignored it if you considered I doubted your input.

Comment: Why do you even bother with multiple consumers if you clearly don't have enough resources for more than one?

Comment: Maybe this is clearer: There are **X resources**. There are **Y consumers**. They consume a resource each **Z seconds**. When there are no resources left and they try to consume, they `await()` for **W seconds** before they die. You would expect the first consumer that requests a resource when there are none left to die and produce other resources(a random amount actually), but sometimes multiple consumers die, as explained. Sorry, I think I screwed up the description in the first place. Anyways, thanks for the input.